# Unable to install SQL named instance as it says RS feature exist, even after dropping it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, installation

We are trying to Un-install a named instance from one of our servers.

But, don't know why it did not un-installed the reporting services even after proper selection was made during uni-install.

Please see the below screenshot what I can see:

[image: RS feature]

But below does not show me any such feature to uninstall

[image: weird]

Moreover, we can see reporting services as running in sql server configuration manager.

Please help what could be possibly missing here?

Comment: You may need to do this [the hard way](https://sqlblog.org/2010/10/25/fun-with-software-uninstalling-sql-server-2008-r2-evaluation-edition).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thanks, I am trying this hard way. Fingers crossed.